# Run webserver on local machine with dynDNS

Tags: networking, router, apache-http-server, port-forwarding, webserver

I created an account at [noip.com](http://www.noip.com) and created a dynamic Host. (test.ddns.net).
On my local machine with IP **192.168.2.128** i run my apache webserver on port **8080** and **443**. 
[image: Apache]

I created a project named "test" which contains the file "test.html" where i simply output "hello world".

On my router (speedport W921 V from telekom i added a port forwarding rule which forwards everything incoming on port 80 to port 8080 of my local machine with ip **192.168.2.128**.

**EDIT**: I also tried to forward everything incomin on port 8080 to port 8080 of my local machine with ip **192.168.2.196**
[image: Port Forwarding]

I've also added the dynDNS entry.
[image: DynDNS Entry]

If i would like to access my project on my local machine, i would simply open
`192.168.2.128:8080/test/test.html` in my browser.
But how can i access this site external?

I tried it like this `test.ddns.net/test/test.html`
But i get "website not reachable".

I am also running the program `DUC v4.1.1`.

Why does it not work? Is the port forwarding not working on the speedport or do i miss some other steps?

**Note**: The real domain name is not "test.ddns.net" i censored it for anonymity.

**EDIT**: I am extremly confused now. My real domain name is NOT `test.ddns.net` as i already told, it is something entirely different. But if i open `test.ddns.net:8080/test/test.html` from my local machine where the webserver runs, then my website with `hello world` open. How is this possible???

Comment: _"But if i open test.ddns.net:8080/test/test.html from my local machine where the webserver runs, then my website with hello world open. How is this possible???"_ This indicates that the DNS servers on the web do resolve to your **public** ip address, which is a good sign. This means that your DynDNS-Serup is very likely to be correct. The problem appears to be with the port mapping/forwarding. But the entries in the Speedport look good.

Comment: But `test.ddns.net` is not my domain name. I registered something like `edwardblack.ddns.net` and not `test.ddns.net`. Thats why i am very confused right now. Can someone explain why i can access my project with this link!?

Comment: No, no, you misunderstood me, what I mean is that if you can open your site by using http://edwardblack.ddns.net:8080 then your DNS is set up properly. If you then cannot open http://edwardblack.ddns.net:80 AKA http://edwardblack.ddns.net then there is a problem with the port forwarding. Do you have a real public IP address?

Comment: Yes this is obvious, but why can i access it via `test.ddns.net:8080` even though i never registered it? This confuses me so hard right now.

Comment: I've got no idea about that. Maybe it's a special entry which echoes your IP, but that would be the first time I've seen something like this. do a `ipconfig /flushdns` in your console (windows) and restart your browser to see if that domain is still behaving that way

Comment: I see: `test.ddns.net` equals to `127.0.0.1`, do a `nslookup test.ddns.net` This is the localhost address, which is your pc

Comment: Ahhh thanks mate :). Now i understand why `test.ddns.net:8080/test/test.html` works for me but not for other computers in my lan...

Answer (score 2):

`nslookup test.ddns.net` responds with `127.0.0.1`, which is the `localhost`. Therefore you're not even sending packets over your home network, but only inside the computer you're working on.

*I tried it like this test.ddns.net/test/test.html But i get "website not reachable".* This is because you're running your server ion port 443 and 8080, not port 80.

You should make sure that you have a real public IPv4 address. It may be the case that you are on IPv6 and when you access IPv4 servers you do that through a *[carrier-grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT)* which will allow you to reach IPv4 servers, but not allow IPv4 clients to reach your IPv4 server, because you don't actually have a public IPv4 one, since it is behind the NAT which you can't configure to do port-forwarding for you. The data transfer between the NAT Gateway and your router would then be over IPv6, and your router would only have a public IPv6 address associated with it. This is called Dual-Stack Lite.

Do Google for "My IP", and google will show you your public ip. Then use http://<IP-address> to open you page. if it opens, then your router's external IP is in effect the public ip address and the port forwarding is fine, which means that the problem is with no-ip.com.

Comment: Sorry i meaned `test.ddns.net:8080/test/test.html`. I have a real public IPv4 address, it is also displayed on no-ip.com

Comment: It may be that no-ip.com is displaying the ip address of the NAT gateway, which is a server you can't configure.

Comment: I guess it does not work because the port forwarding does not work on the speedport W 921 v, many people reported that it does not work with this router.

Comment: Thanks for your infos, i will try this after work and report back. But i really think it is because of my crappy speedport w 921 v which has problems with port forwarding

Comment: If it turns out that the Speedport has this problem only on port 80, but port 443 works, then you may solve your problem by forwarding that one to 8080. In that case you would need to create a certificate for your Apache server, which you can do for free with LetsEncrypt. I'm not completely sure if you can create a certificate without port 80 working, but there are several methods you can use. https would be better for accessing your home anyway. Also, don't forget that it's not that expensive to buy your own domain, ie at hover or namecheap (10€/Year) and allows you to set the DNS-records.

Comment: Thank you for all these informations, very useful! I think the whole port forwarding does not work on this router and i guess they will never patch it, telekom...

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like ngrok for this. Install it and run:

```
ngrok http 8080
```

And it will give you a unique subdomain that you can use to access your server. No port forwarding or anything of that sort required.

Comment: But this will only work on the lan, correct? How should my router know where to send the pakets without port forwarding. hmm

Comment: @EdwardBlack No, it will work from anywhere. Router doesn't need to know about it. ngrok client acts as a proxy. It connects to their server, their server receives all the connections from the outside world... and send the message to the client (which receives it because it initiated the connection and stayed connected waiting for messages) and proxies the request to your application and sends back the response to server which then sends it back to the requester. Just give it a try.

Comment: Now i understand how it works thanks! But this also means that the whole traffic is unsecure, because there is a man in the middle (the proxy). But it is a good solution and i will give it a try and report back.

Comment: @EdwardBlack Yes, the "man in the middle" is the official ngrok server. So, you might not want to use it if you have highly confidential information going through it.